# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtStrategy

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am a newbie in NestJs world. As far as I know, I imported everything needed in the JwtStrategy. I don't know where it went wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

As far as I referred to documetation, Whenever we want to use any entity in a module, we should import that entity in the imports field in the @Module() decorator. I did it.

**jwt.strategy.ts**

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from "passport-jwt";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { UserEntity } from "src/entities/user.entity";
import { AuthPayload } from "src/common/dtos/user.dto";

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private userRepo: Repository<UserEntity>
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: process.env.SECRETKEY
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: AuthPayload): Promise<UserEntity> {
        const { username } = payload;
        const user = this.userRepo.findOne({ where: { username: username } });
        if(!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/entities/user.entity';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.SECRETKEY,
    }),
    PassportModule.register({
      defaultStrategy: 'jwt'
    })
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [PassportModule, JwtStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, OneToMany, JoinTable, BeforeInsert } from "typeorm";
import { AbstractEntity } from "./abstract-entity.abstract";
import { IsEmail } from "class-validator";
import { Exclude, classToPlain } from "class-transformer";
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { CategoryEntity } from "./category.entity";
import { ArticleEntity } from "./article.entity";

@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        length: 80
    })
    fullName: string;

    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        unique: true
    })
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        unique: true
    })
    username: string;

    @Column({
        type: "varchar"
    })
    @Exclude()
    password: string;

    @Column({
        default: null,
        nullable: true
    })
    avatar: string | null;

    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        unique: true
    })
    phoneNumber: string;

    @Column({
        type: "boolean",
        default: false
    })
    isAdmin: boolean;

    @Column({
        type: "boolean",
        default: false
    })
    isStaff: boolean;

    @Column({
        type: "boolean",
        default: false
    })
    isEmailVerified: boolean;

    @OneToMany(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.createdBy)
    @JoinTable()
    categories: CategoryEntity[];

    @OneToMany(type => ArticleEntity, article => article.createdBy)
    @JoinTable()
    articles: ArticleEntity[];

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword() {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    }

    async comparePassword(attempt: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return await bcrypt.compare(attempt, this.password);
    }

    toJSON(): any {
        return classToPlain(this);
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { APP_FILTER, APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { 
  DatabaseConnectionService
 } from "./utils/database-connection.service";
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { ArticlesModule } from './articles/articles.module';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './common/exception-filters/http-exception.filter';
import { ResponseInterceptor } from './common/interceptors/response.interceptor';
import { CategoryModule } from './category/category.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: DatabaseConnectionService
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    ArticlesModule,
    CategoryModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    // {
    //   provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    //   useClass: ResponseInterceptor
    // },
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter
    },
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**database-connection.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmOptionsFactory, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { truncate } from "fs";

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseConnectionService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
    createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return {
            type: "mysql",
            host: process.env.HOST,
            port: parseInt(process.env.PORT),
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DATABASE, 
            entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
            synchronize: true,
            dropSchema: true,
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            logger: "simple-console"
        };
    }
}
```

The Error is as follows:
[image]

Comment: where did you define `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` ? the `user` entity feature should be imported in your typeorm module root import

Comment: Did it in app.module.ts. It used to work before. But it doesn't now? I'll update app.module.ts.

Comment: Ok I can see your problem

Comment: Thank you @yash. I will be waiting for your answer.

Comment: can you add your UsersModule here as well?

Comment: UserModule has nothing to do with it. I just created UserModule and left it untouched for future uses.

Comment: Because from your architecture, i think `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])` should be in your UsersModule?

Comment: Consider there is no UsersModule.

Comment: actually it shouldnt be related your error.. i have a nestjs project very similar architecture with your app. using Typeorm with Passport module, but it;s working well

Comment: It used to work 2 days back. Suddenly after a commit this error is raised. I didn't change anything in the AuthModule. I just added a new column 'tags: string[]' in user.entity.ts. Does it have anything to do with this?

Comment: I don't think so. i used to get similar dependency injections errors before.. I switched to Active Record pattern. it doesnt require a dependency injection and dont need to make a repository instance, you can just use the entity class directly,

Comment: If we use active record pattern, It doesn't go well with the testing right?

Comment: no, it's even better with testing.

Comment: Okay, Thank you @yash. I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error, somewhere you have `JwtStrategy` in your `imports` array. If you need the `JwtStrategy` you should instead import the `AuthModule`, as providers should only be in the `providers` array and should never be in `imports`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to move to Active Record pattern. All what you need to do is just to let your `AbstractEntity` extends `BaseEntity` of TypeOrm.

You can remove all typeorm features imports like:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])
```

and all dependency injections for repository like:

```js
@InjectRepository(UserEntity)
private userRepo: Repository<UserEntity>
```

Just use the entity class for querying:

```js
const user = await UserEntity.findOne({ where: { username } });
```

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try @yash. Thank you for the answer.